# Receiving error I don't understand using Smartadmin Bootstrap Datatables

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, perl, datatable, template-toolkit

Hi I'm trying to implement a Datatable to a webpage that is rendered using Perl and Template Toolkit.
I'm receiving a pop-up error from the data table when it is rendered

This is the error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=datatable_tabletools - Requested unknown                             
parameter '1' for row 1. For more information about this error, please see             
http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

I've read the documentation on this error but I'm still unsure as to why I'm receiving it

Here is the code I believe it is related to.

```
              <table iq-datatable id="datatable_tabletools" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover render_me_as_datatable" width="100%">

                <thead>
                  <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc">ID</th>
                    <th class="sorting">thing</th>
                    <th class="sorting">otherthing</th>
                    <th class="sorting">anotherthing</th>
                    <th class="sorting">morething</th>
                    <th class="sorting">something</th>
                    <th class="sorting"></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  [% FOREACH item IN list%]
                  <tr role="row" class="odd [% item.var%]"
                   [% IF item.var== "CLOSED" %]
                      style="background-color: lightgreen;"
                    [% ELSE %]
                      style="background-color: lightyellow;"
                   [% END %]>
                    <td class="sorting_1">[% item.var%]</td>
                    <td>[% item.var1%]</td>
                    <td>[% item.var2%]</td>
                    <td>[% item.var3 FILTER currency %]</td>
                    <td>[% item.var4%]</td>
                    <td>[% item.var5%]</td>
                    <td> <a href="#" onclick="edit([% item.var6%]);return false;"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View </a> </td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: What Javascript do you use to setup `Datatables`? Have you defined a source for your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation provided in the error, explains it very well.https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

Each cell in DataTables requests data, and when DataTables tries to obtain data for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a warning, **telling you that data is not available where it was expected to be**

> DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}`

where:
`{id}` is replaced with the DOM id of the table that has triggered the error

`{parameter}` is the name of the data parameter DataTables is requesting

`{row-index}` is the DataTables internal row index (row().index()API) for the row that has triggered the error.

`{column-index}` is the column data index (column().index()API) for the column that has triggered the error. The column index information was added in DataTables 1.10.10.

So to break it down, DataTables has requested data for a given row, of the `{parameter}` provided and there is no data there, or it is null or undefined (DataTables doesn't know, by default how to display these parameters - see below if your data does contain these values).

`id` in your case being `datatable_tabletools`

`parameter` in your case being `1`

`row-index` in your case being `row 1`

Finally, to give you a short answer, `column 1` `row 1` in `datatable_tabletools` does not contain the data it is expecting, it is either null or empty or incorrect format.

So have a look at what the code is requesting and see what is not in the table.